# Using Matlab to Minimize the amplitude of this sum

Tags: matlab

I have output matrix Y as:

```
Y=E*A;
```

[image]

where

```
E=Exponential phase vectors (1xM)
A=Fixed complex numbers (MxN)
```

say,

```
 M=4;N=256;
 a = complex(randn(4,256),randn(4,256)); % coefficient matrix of "A"
 theta=has four values
```

**Objective**:

```
 What range of theta will minimize the peak of sum expression of a kth column 
 of "Y" ? i.e.,
```

[image]

Theta subjected to [image]  and m=1,2,...,M

for e.g.,

```
 Min: Y(theta)=Peak{a11*exp(j*theta1)+ a21*exp(j*theta2)+ ...+aM1*exp(j*thetaM)}
```

**My Question:**
Can i use MATLAB to develop a logic to formulate such a problem and solve it ?

I think this is related to Linear Programming with constraints (??).

Comment: Have you tried reading the manual of the Optimization Toolbox which can handle non-linear, constrained optimizations: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/optim/constrained-optimization.html

Comment: Thank you for suggestion.Yes now i am reading that but i am afraid how to frame constraints.I am trying.

Answer (score 0):

My approach will be to use the `fmincon` function from the matlab optimization toolbox.

Your theta vector would be the x vector of solutions you're looking for.
Then specify your problem by defining the objective function f(x) as the max from Yk for all K between 0 and N.

```
       objectiveFunction = @(x) maxY(...
            x,... %
            A);
```

Express your constraint  0<=theta<2pi with the individuals constraints lb and ub (lower and upper bounds).

Then call fmincon

```
        options = optimset('Algorithm','sqp', ...
            'Display', 'iter-detailed',...
            'UseParallel', 'always',...
            'MaxFunEvals', 3000);

        [result, ~, ~] = fmincon(objectiveFunction,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,[],options);
```